# Multiple different UIImageView animations on loop

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I need to do the following animation with an audio clip, on repeat:

- Show image1, image2 and image3 for one second in total (0.33 seconds each)
- Show image4 for five seconds and play an audio file.
- Show image5 and image6 for one second each
- Repeat 3 times

Ideally, I'd like to create an animation, start it animating and leave it to do it's stuff.  i.e. create a UIImageView, build the "animations" array with images, and call "startAnimating".  But to do this I'd need to include image4 15 times and images 5 and 6 3 times so the animation is correct.  I'd also have to schedule the audio for every 2nd second of every 8 second loop.

What other options do I have for creating this type of multi-stage animation?  Should I handle each part separately, with a delegate callback when the animation finishes, which prompts me to then animate the next part of the sequence until the entire animation has repeated 3 times?

Any advice much appreciated.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick rough thought, not been practiced with real code:

1. you need a general purpose UIViewController controlling over everything
2. you need a UIViewController subclass doing each scene, with configurable properties like: image, duration, bgMusic, etc. also define a protocol with delegate method, something like -(void)didAnimationFinish;
3. in your main viewcontroller (described in 1), build an array which
   holds a number of viewcontroller instances
       (described in 2), remember configure them as desired, and assign
       their delegates to main viewcontroller
4. fire the first animation
       viewcontroller either by presentingModalViewController
5. wait get called by delegate methods and move on to the next index of
   array
       (described in 3)

again, just a quick idea

Comment: Thanks Chris.  If I don't get any "easier" solutions, I'll do this and let you know.  It wouldn't be too difficult to do.  However, I'm sure there must be a way to code it all into one object and fire the animation sequence off without having to worry about delegates breaking up the animation.  But maybe not.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would update the image in UIImageView based on an NSTimer. An array/dictionary could store image names and the number of seconds. On timeout set the next image and start another timer. Loop 3 times max.